# SVG: Mask not working as expected

Tags: svg, mask

I have this rather basic SVG with a vertical line going through 4 circles. The mask that I have for the vertical line has the same definition as the line itself, the only difference being the stroke color (#fff in this case) because I want to be able to see through the mask. But, for unknown reasons, the mask still acts as if the color is black, thus hiding the element. If anyone knows why it's behaving like this, please let me know.

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 400 400">

         <defs>
            <mask id="education">
                <path class="through" fill="none" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="2" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M200 325.6v42.5M200 325.6V44.2"/>
            </mask>
        </defs>

        <path class="arrow" fill="#C57773" d="M191.9 41.5l8.1-14 8.1 14"/>
        <path  style="mask: url(#education);" class="through" fill="none" stroke="#58595B" stroke-width="2" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M200 325.6v42.5M200 325.6V44.2"/>
        <path class="circle2" fill="#C95147" d="M200 234.7c-4.6 0-8.3 3.7-8.3 8.3s3.7 8.3 8.3 8.3c4.6 0 8.3-3.7 8.3-8.3s-3.7-8.3-8.3-8.3z"/>

        <path class="circle1" fill="#C95147" d="M200 317.2c-4.6 0-8.3 3.7-8.3 8.3s3.7 8.3 8.3 8.3c4.6 0 8.3-3.7 8.3-8.3s-3.7-8.3-8.3-8.3z"/>

        <path class="circle3" fill="#C95147" d="M200 152c-4.6 0-8.3 3.7-8.3 8.3 0 4.6 3.7 8.3 8.3 8.3 4.6 0 8.3-3.7 8.3-8.3 0-4.5-3.7-8.3-8.3-8.3z"/>

        <path class="circle4" fill="#C95147" d="M200 67.1c-4.6 0-8.3 3.7-8.3 8.3s3.7 8.3 8.3 8.3c4.6 0 8.3-3.7 8.3-8.3s-3.7-8.3-8.3-8.3z"/>

</svg>
```

P.S. Just started tinkering around with SVG, but this (the element dissapearing) happens no matter what shape I define in the mask or what color I give that shape.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

SVG is not like CSS, it doesn't use the stroke-width when calculating dimensions for masks and filters, so you can't mask a shape like a horizontal or vertical line (zero-height/zero-width bounding box) using default mask parameters. Just add "maskUnits="userSpaceOnUse" to your mask element to fix.

```
 <mask id="education" maskUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
```

Comment: Perfect, that did the trick, thank you so much. It's a weird interaction though. Been doing some tests to see what was going on and if I assigned the same mask to a different line declaration, other than pure horizontal or pure vertical, the mask behaved as expected. The more you know, I guess.

Comment: @CosminPislariu Final paragraph here: https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/coords.html#ObjectBoundingBoxUnits

Comment: If you don't specify the mask units explicitly, then the mask size is inferred from the masked object's bounding box.