# stroke-dasharray and stroke-dashoffset to fill a progress

Tags: css, svg

I have 2 svg's that I'm trying to create a progress bar out of. The first one is a curved path, however, I've managed to make it work using `stroke-dasharray="400 400"` and `stroke-dashoffset="-110"` (which is used on a `mask` to fill the progress. It works very well.

The issue I'm having is the straight line, I would like to create a similar progress bar where it fills in the progress, but it's not working and I've been trying to figure out why for maybe 3 hours now... Changing the `stroke-dasharray` and `stroke-dashoffset` I couldn't get the mask to fill in the dots.. I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Here is a reference for the effect I'm trying to achieve

[image]

I've attached my code:

```css
body {
  background: #171B42;
}

.locked {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 44px auto;
  width: 230px;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 180px;
  display:inline-block;
}

.locked img {
  width: 60px;
  margin: 0 26px;
}

.locked.row-1 svg {
  width: 163px;
  height: 175px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -130px;
  right: -50px;
  z-index: -1;
}

.locked.row-2 svg {
  width: 77px;
  height: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -54px;
  right: 74px;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<!-- CURVED PROGRESS  -->

<div class="locked row-1">

  <svg viewBox="0 0 163 175">
  <defs>
    <mask id="mask">
      <path  stroke-dasharray="400 400" stroke-width="10" stroke-dashoffset="-110" stroke="white" d="M0 16.7246C54 16.7246 145.7 11.6246 146.5 85.2246C147.3 158.825 51 158.225 0 158.225"></path>
    </mask>
    <path id="path" fill="none" d="M0 16.7246C54 16.7246 145.7 11.6246 146.5 85.2246C147.3 158.825 51 158.225 0 158.225"></path>
  </defs>
           <!-- solid wide line -->
  <use href="#path" stroke="rgba(255,255,255,0.05)" stroke-width="30"></use>
  <!-- solid narrow line -->
  <use href="#path" stroke="rgba(255,255,255,0.12)" stroke-width="15"></use>
  <!-- dotted full line -->
  <use href="#path" stroke="rgba(255,255,255,0.2)" stroke-width="5" stroke-dasharray="0 20" stroke-linecap="round"></use>
  <!-- dotted masked line -->
  <use href="#path" stroke="rgba(255,255,255,0.8)" stroke-width="5" stroke-dasharray="0 20" stroke-linecap="round" mask="url(#mask)"></use>
        
</svg>

  <img src="https://i.imgur.com/h3ElY2f_d.webp?maxwidth=728&fidelity=grand">
</div>


<!-- LINE PROGRESS  -->

<div class="locked row-2">

  <svg viewBox="0 0 77 17">
  <defs>
    <mask id="mask-2">
      <path  stroke-dasharray="400 400" stroke-width="10" stroke-dashoffset="10" stroke="white" d="M76.6841 8.40967H0.551514"></path>
    </mask>
    <path id="path-2" fill="none" d="M76.6841 8.40967H0.551514"></path>
  </defs>
           <!-- solid wide line -->
  <use href="#path-2" stroke="rgba(255,255,255,0.05)" stroke-width="30"></use>
  <!-- solid narrow line -->
  <use href="#path-2" stroke="rgba(255,255,255,0.12)" stroke-width="15"></use>
  <!-- dotted full line -->
  <use href="#path-2" stroke="rgba(255,255,255,0.2)" stroke-width="5" stroke-dasharray="0 20" stroke-linecap="round"></use>
  <!-- dotted masked line -->
  <use href="#path-2" stroke="rgba(255,255,255,0.8)" stroke-width="5" stroke-dasharray="0 20" stroke-linecap="round" mask="url(#mask-2)"></use>
        
</svg>

  <img src="https://i.imgur.com/h3ElY2f_d.webp?maxwidth=728&fidelity=grand">
</div>
```

Any ideas? Thank you!

Comment: maybe it needs to be a line instead of a path?

Comment: or create a custom rectangle for mask2 since a straight line has no height and mask doesn't seem to consider stroke-width as part of the height...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured out the problem. I found the solution from another stackoverflow question..

> So you can't mask a shape like a horizontal or vertical line (zero-height/zero-width bounding box) using default mask parameters. Just add "maskUnits="userSpaceOnUse" to your mask element to fix.

For more information:
[SVG: Mask not working as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40439831/svg-mask-not-working-as-expected)

So I just ended up having to add `maskUnits="userSpaceOnUse"` to my `mask`

```css
body {
  background: #171B42;
}

.locked {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 44px auto;
  width: 230px;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 180px;
  display:inline-block;
}

.locked img {
  width: 60px;
  margin: 0 26px;
}

.locked.row-1 svg {
  width: 163px;
  height: 175px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -130px;
  right: -50px;
  z-index: -1;
}

.locked.row-2 svg {
  width: 77px;
  height: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -54px;
  right: 74px;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<!-- CURVED PROGRESS  -->

<div class="locked row-1">

  <svg viewBox="0 0 163 175">
  <defs>
    <mask id="mask" maskUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <path  stroke-dasharray="400 400" stroke-width="10" stroke-dashoffset="-110" stroke="white" d="M0 16.7246C54 16.7246 145.7 11.6246 146.5 85.2246C147.3 158.825 51 158.225 0 158.225"></path>
    </mask>
    <path id="path" fill="none" d="M0 16.7246C54 16.7246 145.7 11.6246 146.5 85.2246C147.3 158.825 51 158.225 0 158.225"></path>
  </defs>
           <!-- solid wide line -->
  <use href="#path" stroke="rgba(255,255,255,0.05)" stroke-width="30"></use>
  <!-- solid narrow line -->
  <use href="#path" stroke="rgba(255,255,255,0.12)" stroke-width="15"></use>
  <!-- dotted full line -->
  <use href="#path" stroke="rgba(255,255,255,0.2)" stroke-width="5" stroke-dasharray="0 20" stroke-linecap="round"></use>
  <!-- dotted masked line -->
  <use href="#path" stroke="rgba(255,255,255,0.8)" stroke-width="5" stroke-dasharray="0 20" stroke-linecap="round" mask="url(#mask)"></use>
        
</svg>

  <img src="https://i.imgur.com/h3ElY2f_d.webp?maxwidth=728&fidelity=grand">
</div>


<!-- LINE PROGRESS  -->

<div class="locked row-2">

  <svg viewBox="0 0 77 17">
  <defs>
    <mask id="mask-2">
      <path  stroke-dasharray="400 400" stroke-width="10" stroke-dashoffset="10" stroke="white" d="M76.6841 8.40967H0.551514"></path>
    </mask>
    <path id="path-2" fill="none" d="M76.6841 8.40967H0.551514"></path>
  </defs>
           <!-- solid wide line -->
  <use href="#path-2" stroke="rgba(255,255,255,0.05)" stroke-width="30"></use>
  <!-- solid narrow line -->
  <use href="#path-2" stroke="rgba(255,255,255,0.12)" stroke-width="15"></use>
  <!-- dotted full line -->
  <use href="#path-2" stroke="rgba(255,255,255,0.2)" stroke-width="5" stroke-dasharray="0 20" stroke-linecap="round"></use>
  <!-- dotted masked line -->
  <use href="#path-2" stroke="rgba(255,255,255,0.8)" stroke-width="5" stroke-dasharray="0 20" stroke-linecap="round" mask="url(#mask-2)"></use>
        
</svg>

  <img src="https://i.imgur.com/h3ElY2f_d.webp?maxwidth=728&fidelity=grand">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the second to last instance of `stroke="rgba(255,255,255,0.2)"`, change the opacity from `0.2` to `0.8`.

```css
body {
  background: #171B42;
}

.locked {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 44px auto;
  width: 230px;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 180px;
  display:inline-block;
}

.locked img {
  width: 60px;
  margin: 0 26px;
}

.locked.row-1 svg {
  width: 163px;
  height: 175px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -130px;
  right: -50px;
  z-index: -1;
}

.locked.row-2 svg {
  width: 77px;
  height: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -54px;
  right: 74px;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<!-- CURVED PROGRESS  -->

<div class="locked row-1">

  <svg viewBox="0 0 163 175">
  <defs>
    <mask id="mask">
      <path  stroke-dasharray="400 400" stroke-width="10" stroke-dashoffset="-110" stroke="white" d="M0 16.7246C54 16.7246 145.7 11.6246 146.5 85.2246C147.3 158.825 51 158.225 0 158.225"></path>
    </mask>
    <path id="path" fill="none" d="M0 16.7246C54 16.7246 145.7 11.6246 146.5 85.2246C147.3 158.825 51 158.225 0 158.225"></path>
  </defs>
           <!-- solid wide line -->
  <use href="#path" stroke="rgba(255,255,255,0.05)" stroke-width="30"></use>
  <!-- solid narrow line -->
  <use href="#path" stroke="rgba(255,255,255,0.12)" stroke-width="15"></use>
  <!-- dotted full line -->
  <use href="#path" stroke="rgba(255,255,255,0.2)" stroke-width="5" stroke-dasharray="0 20" stroke-linecap="round"></use>
  <!-- dotted masked line -->
  <use href="#path" stroke="rgba(255,255,255,0.8)" stroke-width="5" stroke-dasharray="0 20" stroke-linecap="round" mask="url(#mask)"></use>
        
</svg>

  <img src="https://i.imgur.com/h3ElY2f_d.webp?maxwidth=728&fidelity=grand">
</div>


<!-- LINE PROGRESS  -->

<div class="locked row-2">

  <svg viewBox="0 0 77 17">
  <defs>
    <mask id="mask-2">
      <path  stroke-dasharray="400 400" stroke-width="10" stroke-dashoffset="10" stroke="white" d="M76.6841 8.40967H0.551514"></path>
    </mask>
    <path id="path-2" fill="none" d="M76.6841 8.40967H0.551514"></path>
  </defs>
           <!-- solid wide line -->
  <use href="#path-2" stroke="rgba(255,255,255,0.05)" stroke-width="30"></use>
  <!-- solid narrow line -->
  <use href="#path-2" stroke="rgba(255,255,255,0.12)" stroke-width="15"></use>
  <!-- dotted full line -->
  <use href="#path-2" stroke="rgba(255,255,255,0.8)" stroke-width="5" stroke-dasharray="0 20" stroke-linecap="round"></use>
  <!-- dotted masked line -->
  <use href="#path-2" stroke="rgba(255,255,255,0.8)" stroke-width="5" stroke-dasharray="0 20" stroke-linecap="round" mask="url(#mask-2)"></use>
        
</svg>

  <img src="https://i.imgur.com/h3ElY2f_d.webp?maxwidth=728&fidelity=grand">
</div>
```